# Is there a way to create programmatically something similar to the Visual Studio 'Go To Implementation' functionality?

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a way to read the contents of a method/function call, something similar to the Visual Studio 'Go To Implementation' functionality (or F11 in debug) but using code.

For example, if I had a C# .cs file that contained the following code:

```
var characters = "AAAAAABBBBBBCCCCCCDDDDDD";
var position = 0;
var newPosition;

//Example #1
myObject.FirstSixCharacters = characters.SubString(position, 6);
position += 6;

//Example #2
myObject.SecondSetOfSixCharacters = AStaticObject.AMethod(characters, position, 6, out newPosition);
position += newPosition;
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to programatically 'drop' into the 'AMethod' method of the 'AStaticObject' object and read the code?

To put the question into context, I have a large enterprise solution that in essence - parses a very large string of characters into lots of DTO fields.  I'm thinking of writing something that will open a 'parser' .cs file, read the contents of the code then determine the position and length of each DTO field based upon the processing applied at the time of the assignment.

This is fairly straight forward to achieve for statements where the field assignment is the result of a simple 'substring' function (*as per example #1, above*).  But on occassion the code uses static objects/methods to extract the characters of the string and update the positional variable (*as per example #2, above*).  This led me to the question - "how can I, programmatically, read the code within the .cs file and when necessary follow calls made to objects/methods when they appear within the code and read the contents of those .cs file"?

Note: The code that I'm attempting to analyse is un-compiled, so decompiliers are not necessary to achieve the result.

Comment: Decompilers do that but probably you'd better to describe what you need this for.

Comment: F12 brings me inside any methods and even DLL's

Comment: What do you hope to achieve with this, what is you overiding goal? what you describe would require you to decompile the DLL, I am not sure but i doubt there is a way to decompile the currently executing code, it has been transformed by the jitter into machine code by this point.

Comment: @Soner Gönül Please could you explain why you edited my original title - your edit lacks details?  Thanks.

Comment: @Steve C# was only necessary in tags not in title hence his edit.